# OS X 10.11 $PATH not working?

Tags: bash, path, terminal, osx-elcapitan

I can't get the `$PATH` to work. What am I doing wrong not understanding?

```
192:~ me$ echo $PATH
/User/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
192:~ me$ ruby rtest
ruby: No such file or directory -- rtest (LoadError)
192:~ me$ cd ~/bin
192:bin me$ ruby rtest
Hello World!
```

why can't it find `rtest` from anywhere if it's inside my `/User/me/bin`?

`rtest` just has 2 lines :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts 'Hello World!'
```

Comment: Should it not be /Users/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin?

Comment: Isn't this a complaint from `ruby` not finding the file `rtest`?  Does `ruby` check your `$PATH` for input files?  In your home directory, there is no `rtest`, but in `~/bin` apparently there is.

Comment: @david-cullen, yes you are right. Fixed it, logged out and back in again, still doesn't work.

Comment: @e0k, Yes, I'm just using the rtest file to see if I can access it from anywhere. Will edit original question with ruby file content.

Answer (score 1):

The `$PATH` is a list of directories for the shell to search for executables and scripts.  In your case, the executable is `ruby` and `rtest` is an argument given to `ruby`.  The shell searches only for `ruby` and runs it, giving `rtest` to Ruby as a string.  Whatever the program does with its arguments is up to to the program.  In your case, it is the name of a file for Ruby to find.  With no directory name given, it looks in the current directory for a file named `rtest`.  If it's there, it runs it, if not it complains.  In your home directory, there is no such file, so `ruby` complains.  When you change to the directory where the file is, it can find it in the current directory, so it runs it.

Try putting the `rtest` in `~/bin` and make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/rtest
```

The first line of your script (`#!/usr/bin/env ruby`) tells the shell how to run it.  You should be able to run it from anywhere:

```
$ rtest
```

(Instead of `ruby rtest`.)  It won't execute the script unless you have permission to execute it.

Comment: Thank you: rtest with chmod to 777 works from outside it's own directory.